# NGINX: Map IP to ASN

Tags: nginx, bgp, as-number, gdpr

in Preparation for GDPR I want my NGINX to not log IP's any longer, but log the AS Number.
To map the ip to an AS number, I would use the BGP datasets from Ripe, and import them in an MySQL table.

But: How do I map the Data inside NGINX? Is the nginx map directive powerful enough to handle the full routing table? Any idea's?

Thanks!

margau